# Numerically integrating $\int_0^\infty x^m e^{- a x^2 - b x - c} dx $

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

Here $a$, $b$, $c$, $m$ are positive. In particular, $m$ is integral. How to do it numerically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coefficient $c$ should be factored away, and $a$ can be normalized to $1$ by a rescaling of the variable. Hence your integral is equivalent to

$$\int_0^\infty x^me^{-x^2}e^{-px}dx$$

which, by the way, can be seen as a Laplace transform.

Wolfram Alpha can give you analytical expressions in terms of the Error function. For small $m$, they are reasonable. E.g. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Laplace+transform+of+x%5E3e%5E%28-x%5E2%29.

It seems that the expression is always of the form

$$P(p)e^{p^2/4}\text{erfc}\left(\frac p2\right)+Q(p)$$ where $P,Q$ are polynomials of degree $m$ and $m-1$ respectively.

For general $m$, you can try your luck with Gauss-Hermite quadrature (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Laplace+transform+of+x%5E3e%5E%28-x%5E2%29), though it works for the bilateral integral. I am not sure that it can be adapted to the unilateral case; you can integrate on $|x|$ instead, but this will introduce an angular point at the origin.

I would not be surprised that you can find a recurrence relation between the integral for different $m$ values, which would in fact lead us to the above polynomials $P,Q$.

---

**Update:**

Stupid me,

$$(-1)^m\int_0^\infty x^me^{-x^2/4}e^{-px}dx$$
 is just the $m^{th}$ derivative on $p$ of

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/4}e^{-px}dx=\sqrt\pi e^{p^2}\text{erfc}(p)$$ (mind the $/4$). Note that $e^{p^2}\text{erfc}(p)$ is known as the Scaled Complementary Error Function, denoted as $\text{erfcx}(p)$.

A CAS tool or `sympy` can give you the expressions of these derivatives (by hand for small $m$). There must be a connection to the Hermite polynomials.

Comment: https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1969-23-107/S0025-5718-1969-0247744-3/home.html

Comment: @Beamer: thanks for this. After my last observation (Update), I guess that the analytical solution is the way to go.

Comment: So you just convert the problem to calculating the special function erfc. Equally difficult. Of course, for this function we might have good algorithm.

Comment: @Beamer: always good to have analytical expressions, which give you better insight, as they relate your problem to a corpus of known facts. 

Indeed there are ready-made implementations of the error function, and notice that we turned the problem to the evaluation of a *single, parameterless* definite integral over a bounded interval, which is easier.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using [Monte Carlo Method for Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration). A python program that generates normally distributed points (since the function has such a similar form) and uses them to obtain the approximate value of the integral is

```
from numpy import pi,exp,sqrt
from numpy.random import randn
a=1
b=2
c=1
m=0.5
N=100000
x=abs(randn(N)/sqrt(2*a))
y=x**m*exp(-a*x**2-b*x-c)
p=2*sqrt(a/pi)*exp(-a*x**2)
approx=sum(y/p)/N
print(approx)
```

where `a`, `b`, `c` and `m` are your integrand constants and `N` denotes the number of Monte Carlo points (you may run this script in an online compiler such as https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php).

Comment: Monte-Carlo integration is notoriously inaccurate. Why do you recommend this for integration of a single-variable smooth function ?

Comment: It is not. This method of integration relies on Law of Large Numbers which guarantees the convergence in probability for large enough $N$. In this question, the MC method gives an approximate answer of $0.07$ with a fairly small elapsed time.

Comment: That's the problem: the error decreases as $1/\sqrt n$, which is terribly slow. To gain one decimal, you need to multiply $n$ by $100$ ! E.g. for four decimals, $n$ should be like one hundred *million*. With a good deterministic method, I am sure one hundred points would be far enough.

Comment: You are right but choosing a rather "good" PDF for the generating MC points can also decrease the error too.

Comment: Let me say it frankly: using a stochastic method here is pathetic.